# Evaluate $ \int_{\mathbb{Q}_p} |x^2|_p \, dx $ with respect to Haar measure on $\mathbb{Q}_p$

Tags: integration, p-adic-number-theory, haar-measure

Is it possible to do calculus problems over the [$p$-adic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number), $\mathbb{Q}_p$ ? Let $d\mu = \frac{dx}{|x|_p}$ be the Haar measure on $\mathbb{Q}_p^\times$.  What would be the value of
$$ \int_{\mathbb{Q}_p} |x|_p^2 \,d\mu $$
Does this question even make sense.  Let's look at the corresponding question over $\mathbb{R}$.
Then $G = \mathbb{R}^\times$ and the Haar measure is $\frac{dx}{x}$.

- $(\mathbb{R}, dx)$
- $(\mathbb{R}^\times,  \frac{dx}{|x|})$

So those are two examples of Haar measures over locally compact groups.  For any measureable set $A \subset \mathbb{Q}_p$ we have:

- $\mu(\mathbb{Z}_p^\times) = 1$
- $\mu(xA) = \mu(A)$ (traslation invariant)
- $\mathbb{Q}_p^\times= \bigcup_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} \; p^k \mathbb{Z}_p^\times$

In the $p$-adic numbers there are certain integrals that can be defined.  The book I'm reading as a spoiler:
$$ \int_{\mathbb{Z}_p \backslash \{ 0\}} |x|^2_p \, d^\times x = \frac{1}{1-p^2} $$
which he argues using the [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series). The only integrable function I could think of is $x^2$, maybe other arithemtic functions are integrable, as well.

Comment: You shouldn't be integrating $p$-adic-valued functions like $x^2$ on $\mathbf Q_p$ with respect to standard Haar measure.  Conventional integration theory with respect to a Borel measure uses real or complex-valued functions.  If you want to integrate with respect to a $p$-adic valued measure, then you would not be using conventional measure theory.

Comment: @KCd you are correct $|x^2|_p$ defines a real-valued function $\mathbb{Q}_p \to \mathbb{R}$ so that the integral is a *real* number.